# How do I resolve this ProductFlavours error

Tags: android-studio

This is the first time I've used Android Studio and I can't build this app. 
Can anyone tell me how to fix this code?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.settingsdeployer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        normal {
            applicationId "org.settingsdeployer"
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.2"
        }

        french {
            applicationId "org.settingsdeployer"
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.2_fr"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

I'm getting these errors when it tries to sync:
ERROR: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
Affected Modules: org.settingsdeployer

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: org.settingsdeployer

I made the requested changes and it sync'd but now I can't make an apk:

That's great, it sync'd the build without errors but now when I try to generate an apk i get more errors. I have no idea what I'm doing!

---

UPDATE:

After adding `flavorDimensions` it sync'd the build without errors but now when I try to generate an apk i get more errors. I have no idea what I'm doing!. Here is the error log:

```
Executing tasks: [:org.settingsdeployer:assembleNormalRelease]

Task :org.settingsdeployer:preBuild UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:preNormalReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:compileNormalReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE Task :org.settingsdeployer:compileNormalReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:checkNormalReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:generateNormalReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:generateNormalReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:javaPreCompileNormalRelease UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:mainApkListPersistenceNormalRelease Task :org.settingsdeployer:generateNormalReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:generateNormalReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE Task :org.settingsdeployer:mergeNormalReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':org.settingsdeployer:_internal_aapt2_binary'.

Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.1-5013011. Searched in the following locations:

file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
file:/C:/Users/Stuart/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar Required by: project :org.settingsdeployer
Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting these errors when it tries to sync: ERROR: All flavors
>   must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
>   Affected Modules: org.settingsdeployer

The flavor dimension problem is happened because you haven't add the `flavorDimensions` to your build.gradle. There must be at least one `flavorDimensions`. Something like this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    // you need to specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        normal {
            // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "org.settingsdeployer"
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.2"
        }
        french {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "org.settingsdeployer"
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.2_fr"
        }
    }
}
```

more details at [Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of
>   2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   Affected Modules: org.settingsdeployer

This warning is telling that we need to use either `api` or `implementation` to replace the `compilation` when adding dependencies. So, change the dependencies block to something like this;

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: That did solve that issue but now when trying to create the apk I get another error :(

Comment: @StuartCunningham: You need to use the same version for your `targetSdkVersion` and support libraries to version 28. It's because you're using `compileSdkVersion 28`

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. What do I need to change? Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: Change `targetSdkVersion 21` to `targetSdkVersion 28`. Then change `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`

Comment: `Sorry to be a pain!`, no problem :)

Comment: Oh no, now I have a new problem!
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 0s
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: org.settingsdeployer

Comment: Great, that is the last part.. change your project/root build.gradle (not the current build.gradle) then add `google()` repo. You can see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#top-level for details.